# Replacing DisplayNameFor() with LabelFor() in MVC(Razor) giving error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**Problem Statement:**

In MVC when I try to use LabelFor() instead of DisplayNameFor() in one of my razor views(.cshtml) for some fields it is giving error like: **System.Collections.Generic.IEnumaerable (Test.Models.TenantModel) does not contain definition for TenantID,Name,Adress1..... But it works fine with DisplayNameFor()**...Why???

**Instead of using:**

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TenantID)
```

**I want to use:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TenantID)
```

Beacuse i'm passing the display name as my second argument for the LabelFor() from viewbag object which is coming from db.

Please suggest me some ways??

**View Code :**

```
   @model IEnumerable<Test.Models.TenantModel>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
    <h2>Tenant</h2>


    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>

    <table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 15px;">
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.TenantControl)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.TenantLanguage.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (item == "1")
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TenantID)
                        </th>
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (item == "2")
                    {
                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                            <th style="text-align: center;">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                            </th>
                            break;
                        }
                    }


                    else if (item == "3")
                    {
                        if (i == 2)
                        {
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address1)
                        </th>
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (item == "4")
                    {
                        if (i == 3)
                        {
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address2)
                        </th>
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (item == "5")
                    {
                        if (i == 4)
                        {
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address3)
                        </th>
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (item == "6")
                    {
                        if (i == 5)
                        {
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CountryID)
                        </th>
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (item == "7")
                    {
                        if (i == 6)
                        {
                            <th style="text-align: center;">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StateID)
                            </th>
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (item == "8")
                    {
                        if (i == 7)
                        {
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CityID)
                        </th>
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (item == "9")
                    {
                        if (i == 8)
                        {
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pin)
                        </th>
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (item == "10")
                    {
                        if (i == 9)
                        {
                        <th style="text-align: center;">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
                        </th>
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var itm in ViewBag.TenantControl)
                {
                    if (itm == "1")
                    {
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TenantID)
                    </td>
                    }
                    else if (itm == "2")
                    {
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    }
                    else if (itm == "3")
                    {
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address1)
                    </td>
                    }
                    else if (itm == "4")
                    {
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address2)
                    </td>
                    }
                    else if (itm == "5")
                    {
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address3)
                    </td>
                    }
                    else if (itm == "6")
                    {
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryModel.Name)
                    </td>
                    }
                    else if (itm == "7")
                    {
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StateModel.Name)
                    </td>
                    }
                    else if (itm == "8")
                    {
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CityModel.Name)
                    </td>
                    }
                    else if (itm == "9")
                    {
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pin)
                    </td>
                    }
                    else if (itm == "10")
                    {
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
                    </td>
                    }
                }
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TenantID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TenantID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TenantID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = GetTenantData();
        return View(result);
    }



public IEnumerable<TenantModel> GetTenantData()
        {
            return (from t in db.Tenant.AsEnumerable()
                    join c in db.Country.AsEnumerable() on t.CountryID equals c.CountryID
                    join s in db.State.AsEnumerable() on t.StateID equals s.StateID
                    join ct in db.City.AsEnumerable() on t.CityID equals ct.CityID
                    orderby t.Name
                    select new TenantModel()
                    {
                        TenantID = t.TenantID,
                        Name = t.Name,
                        Address1 = t.Address1,
                        Address2 = t.Address2,
                        Address3 = t.Address3,
                        CountryID = t.CountryID,
                        StateID = t.StateID,
                        CityID = t.CityID,
                        CountryModel = c,
                        StateModel = s,
                        CityModel = ct,
                        Pin = t.Pin,
                        Phone = t.Phone,

                    });
        }
```

Comment: I don't believe it would work either way, because your model is an `IEnumerable`, which has none of those properties. I think you've gotten confused somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what's the difference between these 2 functions, but when you call DisplayNameFor(model => ...), the type of model is Test.Models.TenantModel, whereas with LabelFor(model => ...), it's IEnumerable (which makes more sense to me, because that's what you declared in the view).
If you really want to make it work in your view, you can use

```
Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().TenantID)
```

but I'm not sure it's working if you have an empty list in your Viewbag.

Comment: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TenantID)

Answer (score 0):

DisplayNameFor doesn't have any overload methods

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
)
```

While LabelFor does, please check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx